# Why is my muting function within a Swift struct able to change one variable, but not another?

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui, immutability

I'm trying to make a kind of stopwatch using SwiftUI and I'm curious why my `Timer` type method can change the value of one variable, `@State var progress: CGFloat = 10.0`, but can not change the status of another variable, `var running = true` ?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var progress: CGFloat = 10.0
    var running = true

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.startLoadingAgain()}) {

            ZStack {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.green, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12.0))
                        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -180))
                    Circle()
                        .trim(from: 0.0, to: progress / 10)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 12.0)
                        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
                    Text("\(Int(progress))")
                    .bold()

                }
                }.padding()
        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }

    mutating func startLoadingAgain() {
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
            withAnimation() {
                self.progress -= 0.1
                self.running = false
                if self.progress <= 0.0 {
                    timer.invalidate()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The 3 situations I have tried are:

1. without the `var running = true` variable declared at the beginning of the struct and without the `self.running = false` in the `func startLoadingAgain()` function, and even when I take `mutating` off that function, everything works fine.
2. When the code is as show, I get an error at `Button(action: {self.startLoadingAgain()}) which says`Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`
3. For good measure I tried adding `@State` before `var running = true` and got the same error as #2

I'm curious why the `running` var is immutable, but the `progress` var is mutable.

Comment: Because that’s how Swift UI works. Only State properties are mutable. Even the very first WWDC video on the topic explains this.

Comment: It's because you're not actually mutating `progress`. `progress` is using the `@State` property wrapper, which internally creates a heap-allocated box to store your value, and holds a reference to that box. The reference never changes, onyl the object pointed at the reference, thus you're not mutating `self`, and don't need to declare your function as `mutating`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica This is good info thank you.  I guess I never tried having '@State' before the variable _and_ not having `mutating` before that function... which makes the code work.  I really thought I had though...